# Issue with GIT command

Tags: linux, git, shell, github

I am trying to execute git clone command to clone source code from github repository. I am using 2.11.1 version. command I run is 
`git clone https://username:password@github.com/repository.git ./localpath`
This works fine at windows machine. But when I am executing from linux machine command is removing @ and throwing error. Execution failure is like

`git clone https://username:passwordgithub.com/repository.git ./localpath Cloning into './localpath'...
error: Couldn't resolve host username:passwordgithub.com while accessing`

Could someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the @ char with a \ ?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @mipadi am using bash shell.

Comment: @user2773289 dont work with \ when I work with jenkins. it is failing.

Comment: @user2773289, it might be a collision with unescaped password.

Comment: I recommend leaving out the username and password and use Git's prompts to let you fill that in after the fact. Something is clearly going on with the parsing (it's creating UN:PW@ as part of the host) but not sure what. Could your password have some special characters in it that is preventing it from reading (such as '\' or other reserved shell characters?). Let me know if the following works with just using the github prompts.
git clone https://github.com/repository.git ./localpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your ssh-keygen generated id to Github so it would not prompt you for password.

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

No need to enter pass-phrase. Output your public key, then copy it to github

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub
```

But, if you really want to go that route.
Enclose them in a single quotation, or do them like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO='https://username:password@github.com/repository.git'
LOCAL_PATH='path/to/wherever'

git clone "$REPO" "$LOCAL_PATH"
```

Note: Use double quotations for variables

Comment: We have fixed this issue using .netrc fiile at linux and _netrc file at windows.

Comment: @Eldo glad you were able to fix it!